# WebView content cut-off

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently copying the whole HTML code in a certain file and saving it on the App.

On load of the app the web contents of the webview is complete but **sometimes** when shifting to from pager item to another it sometimes has this cut-off

I already tried this one:
`mAdvertisementWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true`

It is also appearing on a phone device as well.

[image]